# I can not find GitHub pages after creating new repository

Tags: github

I am creating new GitHub repository but when I go to setting It doesn't showing GitHub Pages section. shortly I don't have GitHub pages after creating new repository. how to fix it or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Github has their own support forum that might be better suited: https://github.community/

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your repository > setting > code and automation > pages.

Then you choose the source main and save it.

You will see the message: Your site is ready to be published at https://yourUsername.github.io/yourRepositoryName/

you have to wait until it be published (Your site is published at https://yourUsername.github.io/yourRepositoryName/).

when you click on it you will see your project. You can travel between the pages of the project, like https://yourUsername.github.io/yourRepositoryName/index.html

hope i could help you